# Android: set size and transparent background of custom marker in GoogleMaps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm having an issue to display properly custom markers on googlemaps. I can set an image, but for some reason it is huge (the normal size of the icon is much smaller than it appears) and although the image is a png, it displays a white background around it...

Here is my code:

```
@Override
        protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered( final MarkerOptions markerOptions) {     
Drawable drawable = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.annotation);
     mImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
     mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.transparent);
     Bitmap icon = mIconGenerator.makeIcon();
     markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon));
}
```

And the result:

[image]

Any idea what I could do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The white background and size comes from the way you are generating your icon (using a `IconGenerator` that is intended to display snippets of information on your markers as bubble icons).

You can set the desired drawable to be the `Marker`'s icon using `BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource()`:

```
@Override
protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered (final MarkerOptions markerOptions) {     
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.annotation));
}
```